# SQLite database problems, Really unsure

Tags: android, sqlite

im trying to create a simple database using SQLite and im coming into an error when running the application. The app runs fine, until i press the button to save data into the database, the error message im getting is..

```
04-19 13:47:00.492 26807-26807/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-19 13:47:00.500 26807-26807/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-19 13:47:00.520 26807-26807/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-19 13:47:31.164 26807-26807/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "tablestock_table": syntax error
04-19 13:47:31.164 26807-26807/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bash1.sqlitediss, PID: 26807
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tablestock_table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tablestock_table (IDNameDatereceivedExpirydate)
```

My Code function is as follows..

```
package com.example.bash1.sqlitediss;
```

`import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;`

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_STOCKDB = "Stock.db";


public static final String DATABASE_STOCKDB = "Stock.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "stock_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
public static final String COL_3 = "Datereceived";
public static final String COL_4 = "Expirydate";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_STOCKDB, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + COL_2 + COL_3 + COL_4 + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name, String Datereceived, String expirydate){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Datereceived);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, expirydate);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1 )
            return false;
    else
            return true;

}



}
```

Comment: `create tablestock_table (IDNameDatereceivedExpirydate)` wrong syntax, It must be `create table stock_table (IDNameDatereceivedExpirydate)`..

Comment: I Cant find the bit you are talking about?

Comment: check the answer below..it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 db.execSQL("create table "  + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + COL_2 + COL_3 + COL_4 + ")");
```

just add a space after "create table "

Comment: Thanks, That seemed to fix the problem, however now passing that, im getting an error that says.. `Error inserting Name=e Datereceived=e Expirydate=e`
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table stock_table has no column named Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO stock_table(Name,Datereceived,Expirydate) VALUES (?,?,?)`

Comment: check this tutorial your sql query has wrong syntax http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: checkout the below answer.. I mentioned what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below methods in your code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " TEXT, " + COL_2 + " TEXT, " + COL_3 + " TEXT, " + COL_4 + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

- In onCreate method you didn't added a space between `create table` AND `TABLE_NAME`.
- In onCreate method you have not specified the datatype of columns.
- In onUpgrade method you had added `TABLE_NAME` in query itself with variable `TABLE_NAME`.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thats all really helpful, thanks its slowly fixing my problem!
I dont understand what you mean by the onUpgrade method however, should it not be called TABLE_NAME?

Comment: It simply means that you're executing query `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME" + TABLE_NAME` in `onUpgrade()` method..which is wrong format of drop table query..because at runtime it'll turn into `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAMEstock_table` which;ll lead to exception.